# Getting dimension when try to get row count of web page table

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am try to get count of row of a web page  table but I am getting dimension of the table.
 I have file called TableRow  class and this class using properties file "webelement.properties" .In properties file i have kept the path of web element

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    public class TableRow {
        protected static WebDriver driver;
        @BeforeClass
        public static void setup() {

            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.get("some url");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

        }
    public Properties getWebElementDetails() throws IOException {
        Properties p = new Properties();

            // Read object repository file
            InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(
                    new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//src//com//properties//webelement.properties"));

            p.load(stream);
            return p;
        }


        public WebElement getElementByXPath(String Key) throws IOException {
            Properties propertiesValue = getWebElementDetails();
            try {

                return driver.findElement(By.xpath(propertiesValue.getProperty(Key)));
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                // If element not found on page then It will return null.

                return null;
            }
        }

        @Test()
        void testLogincase1() throws Exception{

            Thread.sleep(2000);

            System.out.println(getElementByXPath("tab")).getsize());

            }

    }
```

webelement.properties

```
tab=.//*[@id='LinkedForm_Organization_OfficeChild']/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr
```

HTML COde.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">
<table class="linked-record-table data-table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Details</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address 1</th>
<th>Address 2</th>
<th>City</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>Zip</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="data-row" data-is-new="false">
<input id="Organization_OfficeChild_R1_" type="hidden" value="1" name="Organization_OfficeChild_R1_"/>
<input id="Organization_OfficeChild_R1__pky" type="hidden" value="4223" name="Organization_OfficeChild_R1__pky"/>
<td>
<a class="link darker" href="/Office/Details/4223?mode=Edit&_fcl=Organization&_fky=2291">
</td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="data-row" data-is-new="false">
<tr class="data-row new-row-template" data-is-new="true">
<tr class="data-row new-row-template" data-is-new="true">
<tr class="data-row new-row-template" data-is-new="true">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

What i am doing wrong . Please provide solutions.

Comment: plz post the html source code of the table

Comment: I hve posted the HTML code

Comment: provide solution to this post

Answer (score 0):

Hi please identify the row and column of the table as below

```
List<WebElement> myrowcount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='linked-record-table data-table']/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Size of the row is : " + myrowcount.size());

List<WebElement> mycolumncount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='linked-record-table data-table']/tbody/tr/td"));
System.out.println("Size of the column is : " + mycolumncount.size());
```